# PHPStorm navigate to file by name and path using fuzzy search

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I am switching from Vim to PHPStorm. In Vim I had a plugin called CtrlP which could be used to search for files with its path using fuzzy logic.

For example, searching for the string "`defaorderwid`"

Would suggest the file "themes/**defa**ult/views/**order**/**wid**get.php"

(Sublime also has this functionality too ("Goto Anything"), available via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.)

How can I do something similar in PHPStorm? I am aware of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> search, but it searches only names of files without paths.

It is important for me because in current project I have many files named "widget.php" in different folders.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> (twice). Then enter `widget.php` and prepend the folder, or parts of it. Works for me.

They call it "Search Everywhere", or "Double-Shift" feature.

If you want to use abbreviations, you can `CamelCase` or or `CamelHumps` or `SnakeCase` your search, or use Wildcards (`*`). Read [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html#tips).

Comment: Thank you for an answer, and it is a useful feature, but unfortunately, it is not what I need.
"Search Everywhere" searches classes and recent files and names of file, but not files with folders.

Comment: please test yourself, it works. for example, type themes/default/views/order/widget.php

Comment: @user2665732 `Navigate | File` as well as `Search Everywhere` searches trough the path. Have you bothered to check help pages? http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html#d713652e409

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you.
While it is still not perfect (requires "/" delimiter), it is quite usable.
@LazyOne, I have checked some docs, at least these pages http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html and http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-to-file-path.html . Thank you too for pointing me out.

Comment: added note on useful abbreviations: CamelCase, CamelHumps, SnakeCase, Wildcard.

Comment: CamelCase does nothing...?

Answer (score 4):

if you have files like:

```
/buildings/users/create.blade.php
/rooms/users/create.blade.php
/parks/users/create.blade.php
```

you can search like that:

```
1. double press SHIFT
2. type: buil/creat (first letters of folder and file)
3. PHPStorm will find: buildings/users/create.blade.php
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a file (or directory) you can use:

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
macOS: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

(Double tapping <kbd>Shift</kbd> works too, but it also searches for classes, symbols and actions, and so is slower.)

Despite what you say, it does search for fragments of directories and filenames --
 but only if they're separated by slashes:

[image]

Developers have been asking JetBrains for this without the need for "/". Register your desire for it to be added here: [IDEA-112841](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112841)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for file in a particular path use **Ctrl+Shift+N**

whith : **themes/d/v*s/*/widget** Or **t/d/v/o/wid** etc ...

will display widget.php file in themes/default/views/order path